# login with param url spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have difficulty using Spring Security. I need auto login with parameter in URL.

Example:
I access the URL with username and password parameters
link/collectsys/mainlogin.zul?username=ADMIN&password=12345678.
When it is accessed, I hope it will log in automatically, such as filling in the username and password and clicking the login button.

I'm having trouble finding the action on the login button because I'm using Spring Security. What should I look for in the Spring documentation? I'm using Spring Security version 5.5.3.

Comment: Please specify Spring and Spring Security version you are using

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm using Spring Security version 5.5.3

Answer (score 0):

You would need to generate a token when you login. This token is then used by the user's client to interact with the REST APIs protected by spring security.

So the login method would need to return to the client an access token that then will be saved in the client's session or cookies to be then reused whenever a call to the backend is made.

One of the common used solutions is the JWT of which you can find a really comprehensive guide here:

https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication/

If you really cannot change much of the application then you should look into the `OncePerRequestFilter` that enables you to filter requests of the spring boot application

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws
            ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username"); 
        String pw = request.getParameter("password"); 
        User user = database.getUser(username);
        if(user.getPw().equals(pw))
            logger.info("Successfully authenticated user  " + userName);
        else throw new SomeException();
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

This way which ever request gets to your application passes through this filter once before getting to the controller logic itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
for my current case, i don't use api backend, my application from frontend directly to controller and database.

for my case now.
I have a web application A, when I have logged in to application A there is a menu to open application B. when it is opened it will open a new tab in the browser with the username and password via the url.

I hope, I can directly login in application B with the same user in application A.
in application B there is a login form, using spring-security.

Comment: does it allow spring-security login with parameters brought in from application B in its url.

the example url is link/collectsys/mainlogin.zul?username=ADMIN&password=12345678

Comment: I've added another option in case you really cannot change your authentication flow